# how to input x and y as much as you could?

Tags: python

[this is what I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTDqI.jpg)

apparently with what I use I can put as many x and y as I possibly could. but I couldn't make it automatically print out as much as the x and y input. is there a way to do that?

Comment: are the count of x values and y values will be the same or maybe different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers in the inputs are separated by spaces, you can try this:

```
s = input("Enter x: ")
a = input("Enter y: ")
s = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
a = [int(x) for x in a.split()]
for i in range(len(s)):
    print((s[i], a[i]))
```

If the numbers in the inputs are not separated by spaces, you can try this:

```
s = input("Enter x: ")
a = input("Enter y: ")
s = [int(x) for x in str(s)]
a = [int(x) for x in str(a)]
for i in range(len(s)):
    print((s[i], a[i]))
```

Comment: I think case of strings and characters need to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Assume l1 and l2 are the lists you want to print...

```
for x,y in zip(l1,l2):
    print((x, y))
```

So your code should look like this

```
s = input("Enter x: ")
a = input("Enter y: ")
s = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
a = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
for x, y in zip(s, a):
    print((x, y))
```